# Android - Picasso removes margin after loading Image

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I am adding **`ImageView`** in **`LinearLayout`** programmatically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 3);
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); //SETTING MARGIN HERE
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    mBrandLinearLayout.addView(imageView); // adding in LinearLayout

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mBrandArrayList.get(i).getBrandLogo())
            .resize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_photo_24dp)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_photo_24dp)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Without loading images with **Picasso** it works fine with sample of drawable images but after adding **Picasso** code it removes **Top** and **Bottom** margins.

> Note: I have tried to load image first and set image after loading
>   image but it is also not working.

Is there any way to set **Margins** with **Picasso**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with adding **-10** in

**`new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 3 - 10);`**

and

**`.resize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 3 - 10)`**

#### Edited Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 3 - 10); //ADDED -10
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    mBrandLinearLayout.addView(imageView);

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mBrandArrayList.get(i).getBrandLogo())
            .resize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 3 - 10) //ADDED -10
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_photo_24dp)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_photo_24dp)
            .into(imageView);
}
```